# ¿Como podria leer los nombres de los ficheros de una url?

Tags: c#, web, wordpress-imagenes

me gustaría leer los nombres de todas las imágenes que hay en un directorio de una página web (WordPress).
Estas imágenes están en "https://paginaweb.com/wp-content/uploads/gb/" tengo acceso de administrador al WordPress, pero no sé ni por donde empezar.
Si lo tengo de hacer mediante API, un httprequest...
Me podéis guiar por favor

Answer (score 1):

Si las imágenes las has añadido mediante la interfaz de administración de WordPress (en Media), puedes acceder al listado haciendo una petición a la API REST de WordPress utilizando esta URL:

`https://paginaweb.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/media`

La documentación oficial la puedes encontrar [aquí](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#list-media).
Dependiendo de cómo esté configurado WordPress, la URL del API puede cambiar. Échale un ojo a [este](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/key-concepts/#routes-endpoints) apartado de la documentación también.

Si la lectura quieres hacerla directamente en el sistema de ficheros utilizando C# (la pregunta tiene el tag `C#`), puedes obtener una lista de ficheros del directorio utilizando el método `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()` ([documentación aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles)) y los nombres de los ficheros con `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` ([documentación aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename)).

Comment: Buenas, si la lectura ha de ser desde c#, imagino que para poder hacer la lectura mediante API REST, necesitaré de alguna librería para ayudarme, buscaré algo al respecto.
La lectura directa al sistema de ficheros, no puede ser, ya que es un servidor remoto.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba https://restsharp.dev/